# Making an Ajax call and returning a boolean value in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I want to make an ajax call (using JQuery) in an ASP.NET MVC application and return a boolean value, how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Well, probably the best solution is to use JSON serialization.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string parameter)
    {
        //do something with parameter
        bool result = true;
        return Json(new ActionInfo()
        {
            Success =result,     
        });
    }
```

The ActionInfo is just a simple class with one property, boolean Success.Then, jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "YourController/DoSomething?parameter=pValue",
data: {},
dataType: "json",
success: function(actionInfo) {

    alert(actionInfo.Success);

}});
```

Hope this helps.